# openssl error "EVP_DigestInit_ex:initialization error" using EVP-library

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a problem with openssl and the EVP-functions:
When I execute the following code

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void hash(ENGINE* eng) {
    EVP_MD_CTX *_mdctx(EVP_MD_CTX_create());
    int ret = EVP_DigestInit_ex(_mdctx, EVP_sha512(), eng);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(_mdctx);
    if(1 == ret) { 
        std::cout << "Finished successfully (with eng=" << eng << ")" << std::endl;
        return;
    } else {
        std::array<char, 256> err_str;
        ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), err_str.data(), err_str.size());
        std::cout << "Error at Digest (engine: " << ENGINE_get_id(eng) << "): " << err_str.data() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();

    hash(nullptr);
    for(ENGINE *eng = ENGINE_get_first(); eng != nullptr; eng = ENGINE_get_next(eng)) {
        hash(eng);
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Finished successfully (with eng=0)
Error at Digest (engine: rdrand): error:260BA093:engine routines:ENGINE_get_digest:unimplemented digest
Error at Digest (engine: dynamic): error:06080086:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:initialization error
```

I understand, that rdrand doesn't support digest, but why do I get an initialization error, when I use the dynamic engine? In particular why does it work, when I call `EVP_DigestInit_ex` with `eng=nullptr`?

The code can be compiled with `g++ example.cpp -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -O2 -lssl -lcrypto`. I am using g++, version 6.3.0 and openssl 1.1.0f.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile as C and is not. Do not tag as C, if you're actually using C++. Also, in C++, having `void` in the arguments list is equivalent to having nothing. It's generally a better idea to leave the argument list empty, instead of using the C-style.

Comment: @tambre - OpenSSL is a C library. He should probably tag as both since there are different rules that apply and there could be bad interactions. For example, accessing the inactive member in an union is well defined in C but undefined in C++.